# PowerShell processing of large users very slow - Is there a better way?

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server, export-to-csv

I have been using for Office365 Licence Tracking. Actually it looks like good but but it takes too much time to complete the process. most of time is spent by Get-MsolUser it may be improved calculating them in parallel (while processing user 1 you're already fetching user 2's data and so on...) BTW we have about 3000+ cloud user How can I improve the speed of the script?

```
$T1 = @()
$O365Users = Get-MsolUser -All
ForEach ($O365User in $O365Users)
{
    $ADuser = Get-ADUser -Filter { UserPrincipalName -eq $O365User.UserPrincipalName } -Properties whenCreated, Enabled, lastlogondate
    $O365Stats = Get-MailboxStatistics $O365User.DisplayName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $O365Smtp =  Get-Recipient $O365User.DisplayName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    If ($O365Stats -and $O365Smtp) {
    If (($ADUser.Enabled -eq $true) -and ($O365User.isLicensed -eq $true))
    {
        $T1 += New-Object psobject -Property @{
            CollectDate = $(Get-Date);
            ADUserUPN = $($ADUser.UserPrincipalName);
            O365UserUPN = $($O365User.UserPrincipalName);
            ADUserCreated = $($ADUser.whenCreated);
            ADUserEnabled = $($ADUser.Enabled);
            ADLastLogonDate = $($ADUser.LastLogonDate);
            O365Licensed = $($O365User.isLicensed);
            O365LastLogonTime = $($O365Stats.LastLogonTime);
            O365SMTPAddress = $($O365Smtp.PrimarySMTPAddress)
        }
    }
}
}
$T1 = $T1 | Sort-Object -Property ADUserCreated
$T1 | Format-Table
$T1 | Export-Csv -Path $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation
Write-Host "Output to $OutputFile"
```

Comment: just like you said, parallel it out

Comment: thanks man like you said how can I reconstruct my script? please clarify

Answer (score 0):

To give you a set off with parallelism in Powershell.

I would like you to go through the PS Workflows.

We have **-parallel** in that which will help you in parallel call.

Apart from that, we have one function for **Invoke-Parallel**

This is the link for it : [Invoke-Parallel Function](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PowerShell/blob/master/Invoke-Parallel.ps1)

**Note:** Examples are mentioned inside the function itself . You can use get-help with that function also once compiled.

Comment: thanks man how can I combine my script with Invoke-Parallel function?  Am I correct ? Invoke-Parallel -scriptfile myscript.ps1  -runspaceTimeout 10 -throttle 10

Comment: @Arbelac: Yes that should do your work ... Check it out

Answer (score 0):

Using a pipeline, filtering early on, and avoiding appending to an array should already speed things up considerably:

```
Get-MsolUser -All | Where-Object {
    $_.IsLicensed
} | ForEach-Object {
    $upn = $_.UserPrincipalName
    Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$upn'" -Properties whenCreated, Enabled, lastlogondate
} | Where-Object {
    $_.Enabled
} | ForEach-Object {
    $O365Stats = Get-MailboxStatistics $_.DisplayName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $O365Smtp  = Get-Recipient $_.DisplayName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($O365Stats -and $O365Smtp) {
        New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
            'CollectDate'       = Get-Date
            'ADUserUPN'         = $_.UserPrincipalName
            'O365UserUPN'       = $_.UserPrincipalName
            'ADUserCreated'     = $_.whenCreated
            'ADUserEnabled'     = $_.Enabled
            'ADLastLogonDate'   = $_.LastLogonDate
            'O365Licensed'      = $true
            'O365LastLogonTime' = $O365Stats.LastLogonTime
            'O365SMTPAddress'   = $O365Smtp.PrimarySMTPAddress
        }
    }
} | Sort-Object -Property ADUserCreated | Export-Csv -Path $OutputFile -NoType
```

Also, why the heck is everybody so infatuated with subexpressions? Use them where you need them. Don't obfuscate your code with them when they're unnecessary.

Comment: you are right about unnecessary filtering man I'll check this asap.

Comment: I am getting a warning like : By default, only the first 1000 items are returned. Use the ResultSize parameter to specify the number of items returned. To return all items, specify "-ResultSize Unlimited". Be awa
re that, depending on the actual number of items, returning all items can take a long time and consume a large amount of memory. Also, we don't recommend storing the results in a variable. In
stead, pipe the results to another task or script to perform batch changes.   What do you recommended?

Comment: Where exactly do you get that warning? AFAICS all cmdlets except `Get-MsolUser` should be returning individual items, but according to the docs the parameter for `Get-MsolUser` should be `-MaxResults` (which has a default of 500), not `-ResultSize`.

Comment: From what I see I have been getting continously this warnings during script running also  I don't know exactly where warnings come from. Lastly if I run my above script (unedited) then I am not getting warnings like that.

Comment: Try my updated answer. Are you still getting that warning? Does it remain if you remove the `Sort-Object` step?

Comment: unfortunately same issue happens with and/or without `Sort-Object`

Comment: Then try running the pipeline step by step to see at which point the warnings appear (start with just `Get-MsolUser -All`, then add the first `Where-Object`, then the first `ForEach-Object`, and so on).

Comment: The thought came to my mind how can I fetch directly Lastlogon stats and primary smtp address via `Get-MsolUser` ? So no need `Get-Recipient` and `Get-MailboxStatistics`command. So how can I combine these ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132902/discussion-between-arbelac-and-ansgar-wiechers).

Comment: Please do not move the target. If you have a new or followup question: post a new question.

Comment: BTW I have catched something
Creating a new session for implicit remoting of "Get-MailboxStatistics" command... 
WARNING: By default, only the first 1000 items are returned. Use the ResultSize parameter to specify the number of items returned. To return all items, specify "-ResultSize Unlimited".